# Pygame: What is the best way to display these ships and their movement from sprite sheet?

Tags: python, pygame, sprite, 2d-games, sprite-sheet

Attached below is one of the sprite sheets I am using.  Right now, I am wondering the best way to display the ships with their animation when moving.  The ships have 9 frames.  I have found old examples with deprecated code, or examples that have you break the images into individual files.  I would love for someone to show me the best way to use these sprites as they are.  Thank you for your time.

[image: Sprite Sheet]

Comment: I should have been more clear though. The ships' animations are directional images, and should show when the direction is moved, not as a continuous loop while moving in any direction. You can see on the spritesheet, the far right ship is the idle image, then to the left is what happens when hitting RIGHT+LEFT, then the next image is when you hit DOWN, then DOWN+LEFT etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*What is the best way* can't be answered, because in the end that's subjective; and depends on your own goals. Best performance? Easiest code? Most flexible code?

You could start with something like this I hacked together during my last boring meeting:

```
import pygame
import random
from pygame import Vector2

SPRITE_SHEET = None

GREEN_SHIP  = pygame.Rect(0, 292, 32, 32)
RED_SHIP    = pygame.Rect(0, 324, 32, 32)
BLUE_SHIP   = pygame.Rect(0, 356, 32, 32)
YELLOW_SHIP = pygame.Rect(0, 388, 32, 32)


class EnemyController:

    def __init__(self):
        self.direction = Vector2(1, 0)

    def update(self, sprite, events, dt):
        if not pygame.display.get_surface().get_rect().contains(sprite.rect):
            self.direction *= -1
        sprite.direction = self.direction

class PlayerController:

    movement = {
        pygame.K_UP:    Vector2( 0, -1),
        pygame.K_DOWN:  Vector2( 0,  1),
        pygame.K_LEFT:  Vector2(-1,  0),
        pygame.K_RIGHT: Vector2( 1,  0)
    }

    def update(self, sprite, events, dt):
        pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        v = Vector2(0, 0)
        for key in PlayerController.movement:
            if pressed[key]:
                v += PlayerController.movement[key]

        sprite.direction = v

        for e in events:
            if e.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if e.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    sprite.groups()[0].add(Explosion(sprite.pos))

class Animation:
    def __init__(self, frames, speed, sprite):
        self.sprite = sprite
        self.speed = speed
        self.ticks = 0
        self.frames = frames
        self.running = 0
        self.start()

    def cycle_func(self, iterable):
        saved = []
        for element in iterable:
            yield element
            saved.append(element)
        if hasattr(self.sprite, 'on_animation_end'):
            self.sprite.on_animation_end()
        while saved:
            for element in saved:
                yield element
            if hasattr(self.sprite, 'on_animation_end'):
                self.sprite.on_animation_end()
    def stop(self):
        self.running = 0
        if self.idle_image:
            self.sprite.image = self.idle_image

    def start(self):
        if not self.running:
            self.running = 1
            self.cycle = self.cycle_func(self.frames)
            self.sprite.image = next(self.cycle)

    def update(self, dt):
        self.ticks += dt
        if self.ticks >= self.speed:
            self.ticks = self.ticks % self.speed
            if self.running:
                self.sprite.image = next(self.cycle)

class AnimatedSprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, pos, frames, speed):
        super().__init__()
        self.animation = Animation(frames, speed, self)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=pos)
        self.pos = Vector2(pos)
        self.animation.start()

    def update(self, events, dt):
        self.animation.update(dt)

class Explosion(AnimatedSprite):

    frames = None

    def __init__(self, pos):
        if not Explosion.frames:
            Explosion.frames = parse_sprite_sheet(SPRITE_SHEET, pygame.Rect(0, 890, 64, 64), 6, 4)

        super().__init__(pos, Explosion.frames, 50)

    def on_animation_end(self):
        self.kill()

class DirectionalImageSprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    directions = [(1,0),(1,-1),(0,-1),(-1,-1),(-1,0),(-1,1),(0,1),(1,1),(0,0)]

    def __init__(self, pos, directional_images_rect):
        super().__init__()
        images = parse_sprite_sheet(SPRITE_SHEET, directional_images_rect, 9, 1)
        self.images = { x: img for (x, img) in zip(DirectionalImageSprite.directions, images) }
        self.direction = Vector2(0, 0)
        self.image = self.images[(self.direction.x, self.direction.y)]
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=pos)
        self.pos = pos

class SpaceShip(DirectionalImageSprite):

    def __init__(self, pos, controller, directional_images_rect):
        super().__init__(pos, directional_images_rect)
        self.controller = controller
        self.speed = 3

    def update(self, events, dt):
        super().update(events, dt)

        if self.controller:
            self.controller.update(self, events, dt)

        self.image = self.images[(self.direction.x, self.direction.y)]
        if self.direction.length():
            self.pos = self.pos + self.direction.normalize() * self.speed

        self.rect.center = int(self.pos[0]), int(self.pos[1])

def parse_sprite_sheet(sheet, start_rect, frames_in_row, lines):
    frames = []
    rect = start_rect.copy()
    for _ in range(lines):
        for _ in range(frames_in_row):
            frame = sheet.subsurface(rect)
            frames.append(frame)
            rect.move_ip(rect.width, 0)
        rect.move_ip(0, rect.height)
        rect.x = start_rect.x
    return frames

def main():
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
    global SPRITE_SHEET
    SPRITE_SHEET = pygame.image.load("ipLRR.png").convert_alpha()
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    dt = 0
    all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group(
        SpaceShip((400, 300), PlayerController(), YELLOW_SHIP),
        SpaceShip((400, 100), EnemyController(), GREEN_SHIP)
    )

    while True:
        events = pygame.event.get()

        for e in events:
            if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return

        all_sprites.update(events, dt)

        screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
        all_sprites.draw(screen)
        pygame.display.flip()
        dt = clock.tick(120)

main()
```

[image]

I pass the function `parse_sprite_sheet` the image, along with the position and size of the first frame of the animation/bunch of related sub-images (using a `Rect`). Also, I pass the number of images in the row and the number of rows (since the explosion animation uses 4 rows with 4 images each). Then I use [`subsurface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.subsurface) the get the part of the sprite sheet I'm interested in in a nested loop.

---

The `Animation` class is updated by the sprite it's attached to and changes the image of the sprite when enough time has passed.

Also a method named `on_animation_end` is called on the sprite once the animation ends. I use this to kill the `Explosion` sprites once the explosion is done.

---

For the directional images of `SpaceShip`, I define the directions in a list once (in the correct order) and then attach each direction an image by creation a dictionary.

This way I can easily look up the correct image, since the direction the `SpaceShip` is heading is stored in the `direction` attribute.

---

That's it basically. 
Some animations in your sprite sheet are a little more tricky, as the size of the tile changes, but it's doable.

You'll get the idea.

Comment: That's awesome, and definitely helps me out so much. I should have been more clear though. The ships' animations are directional images, and should show when the direction is moved, not as a continuous loop while moving in any direction. You can see on the spritesheet, the far right ship is the idle image, then to the left is what happens when hitting RIGHT+LEFT, then the next image is when you hit DOWN, then DOWN+LEFT etc

Comment: @SeanFord OK, somehow I missed that. I updated my answer :-)

Comment: How can i add this function to a class Player?  I have a new foundation for my game, and would like to implement the movement there. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62184961/coding-graphics-to-new-game-foundation#comment109987651_62188716